# solve error showing a missing name space in imports. Razor

Tags: c#, user-interface, blazor-webassembly

error showing I do not have Layout in my project

[image: error showing I do not have Layout in my project]

deleted the folder and created the same folder again error was solved but when I debug the project I get the same error.
Also closed and re-opened the project. but when debugging the error is there.